# Compiling an external library on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, g++

Good Day Everyone,

N.B - This problem has been solved - I have provided my own solution in the answer section however the solution provided by Jonathan is much shorter. Nevertheless, this was the following question I originally posted:

I am basically trying to compile a serial library (for UART communication) on Linux however I am not really sure how to correctly compile (I have mentioned what I have done so far below), any suggestions would be highly valuable. I am using the serialib library - which is composed of 2 main files (**serialib.h** and **serialib.cpp**) , you may directly view the source code of these files here (scroll all the way to the bottom and view the files in new tabs): http://serialib.free.fr/html/classserialib.html

I transferred these files (serialib.h and serialib.cpp) to my BeagleBone Black micro-controller which is running Debian (Wheezy) , g++/gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14) 4.6.3. I wrote my own program (**uart.cpp** is my file name) to access the functions provided by this library, this is what I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "serialib.h"
#ifdef __linux__
#define DEVICE_PORT "/dev/ttyO1"
#endif
int main()
{
    serialib LS;
    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see I am trying to access the 'seriallib' class. serialib.h, serialib.cpp and uart.cpp are all in the home directory. I also manually added the iostream library in serialib.cpp as I did not see it being declared in the original source code.

Now I am really unsure of how to compile such external libraries but so far I tried the following steps:

1. **g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC serialib.c** to convert to PIC which gives the following error:

distcc[3142] (dcc_parse_hosts) Warning: /home/debian/.distcc/zeroconf/hosts contained no hosts; can't distribute work
distcc[3142] (dcc_zeroconf_add_hosts) CRITICAL! failed to parse host file.
distcc[3142] (dcc_build_somewhere) Warning: failed to distribute, running locally instead

2. **g++ serialib.cpp -L /home/debian/serialib.h** which gives the following error:

/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x30): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
distcc[3210] ERROR: compile serialib.cpp on localhost failed

As of now I am still finding out how to compile this and if I manage to work this out then I'll post my solution here too. Once again any suggestion will be highly valuable. Thank you all :) .

Comment: The compilation error seems to be rather straightforward: the compiled code does not have a `main()`. What's so unclear about that?

Comment: Both for static and dynamic libraries, there are plenty of tutorials if you just search a little.

Comment: Cannot copy and paste code from your screenshot.

Comment: @Sam it is unclear (to the OP) what to do with this information. A library shouldn't have `main()`.

Comment: @n.m. is right, there is no main(), apologies if i provided the source code in the form of a screenshot, here is the code in raw format:

#include<iostream>
#include "serialib.h"
#ifdef __linux__
#define DEVICE_PORT "/dev/ttyO1"
#endif
int main()
{
       serialib LS;
       return 0;
} 

This is a bit different than the source code in the screenshot however this is good enough as the class being accessed is external.

Comment: It seems your Linux computer is configured to use distcc and this configuration is broken. I don't recommend you to deal with distcc at this point. Try disabling distcc (read the manual). This is only a warning though.

Comment: @n.m. Noted. However first I would want to know whether my steps are correct or incorrect (still researching on that), after that I can look into the other tools that possess problems. :)

Comment: Ignore the word 'library'. You have two C++ source files (seruallib.cpp and uart.cpp) and one header. Build a program out of them. Don't try to build any libraries, they are not needed and only distract you.

Comment: Your first step is correct. The second one is from outer space.

Comment: [edit] your question, don't post updates in comments.

Comment: Your first command shows `serialib.c` but you said the file is `serialib.cpp` - which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. `g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC serialib.c` to convert to PIC which gives the following error:

The "error" is not an error, it's a warning, telling you that your distcc setup is broken, but that it compiled locally.

That command doesn't "convert to PIC", it compiles the file `serialib.c` and produces a compiled object file, `serialib.o`

> 2. `g++ serialib.cpp -L /home/debian/serialib.h`

This is just nonsense. It tries to build a program from `serialib.cpp` and use the directory `/home/debian/serialib.h` (which isn't a directory!) to find libraries.

You don't need to "compile a library" you can just compile both the source files and link them together into a program. Either:

```
g++ -c serialib.cpp 
g++ -c uart.cpp
g++ serialib.o uart.o -o uart
```

Or all in one command:

```
g++ serialib.cpp uart.cpp -o uart
```

You should read [An Introduction to GCC](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/) to understand the commands, not just enter bogus commands without understanding them.

Comment: That's correct, realized all of those are true only after posting the question, should have researched a bit more. Same result as my posted solution and much shorter indeed. Thank you for the reference to the GCC guide and providing a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem, hope this helps for all the future readers with similar problems. I have my own source code uart.cpp (Given in the question) which I want to compile, the external library is ***serialib*** that contains two main files (serialib.h and serialib.cpp), you will want to replace the following commands with respect to the files you have

**Step 1: Compiling with position independent code**

*g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fpic serialib.cpp*

**Step 2: Creating a shared library**

*g++ -shared -o libserialib.so serialib.o* , here the library is **libserialib.so**.

**Step 3: Linking your source code with library**

*g++ -L /home/debian -lserialib uart.cpp -o uart*

*g++ -L /home/debian -Wall -o test uart.cpp -lserialib*

You may save the library at a different path and you may have a different name of course. Suppose you have a library called libabc.so at the directory /home/user/myDir then the commands will be like:

*g++ -L /home/user/myDir -labc your_code.cpp -o your_code*

*g++ -L /home/user/myDir -Wall -o test your_code.cpp -labc*

`test` is out own program, lserialib is actually looking for libserialib.so and not serialib.o as gcc/g++ assumes all libraries start with `lib` and end with .so or .a and you can see the same goes for labc as it will look for libabc.so thus it is important to make sure your library name begins with `lib` and ends with .so or .a

**Step 4: Making library available at run time**

Here we provide the path where the library is actually stored, I saved it in the directory /home/debian which is why my command looks like:

*export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/debian:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH*

if your library is saved at /path/to/file then the command will look like:

*export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/file:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH*

This is to help the loader find the shared library and to view this path: *echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH* and to unset this: *unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH*

To execute the program type either ./test or ./uart and in case of any modification to the main source code (uart.cpp in this case) , simply repeat step 3. I found the following link very useful: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html . Thank you to all of you who took time to read this question and especially those who gave me suggestions. If anyone has more or better solutions, feel free to post them here to assist future readers :).